# Explode JSON array into rows

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, explode, convertfrom-json

I have a dataframe which has 2 columns" "ID" and "input_array" (values are JSON arrays).

```
ID   input_array
1    [ {“A”:300, “B”:400}, { “A”:500,”B”: 600} ]
2    [ {“A”: 800, “B”: 900} ]
```

Output that I need:

```
ID A      B
1  300    400
1  500    600
2  800    900
```

I tried `from_json`, `explode` functions. But data type mismatch error is coming for array columns.

[Real data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhnt7.jpg)
In the image, the 1st dataframe is the input dataframe which I need to read and convert to the 2nd dataframe. 3 input rows needs to be converted to 5 output rows.

Comment: Main issue is : column "Input_array" data type is "string" . Had it been array or map it will be very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 interpretations of what input (column "input_array") data types you have.

- **If it's a string...**

  ```py
  df = spark.createDataFrame(
      [(1, '[ {"A":300, "B":400}, { "A":500,"B": 600} ]'),
       (2, '[ {"A": 800, "B": 900} ]')],
      ['ID', 'input_array'])
  df.printSchema()
  # root
  #  |-- ID: long (nullable = true)
  #  |-- input_array: string (nullable = true)
  ```

  ...you can use [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#from_json) to extract Spark structure from JSON string and then [`inline`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#inline) to explode the resulting array of structs into columns.

  ```py
  df = df.selectExpr(
      "ID",
      "inline(from_json(input_array, 'array<struct<A:long,B:long>>'))"
  )
  df.show()
  # +---+---+---+
  # | ID|  A|  B|
  # +---+---+---+
  # |  1|300|400|
  # |  1|500|600|
  # |  2|800|900|
  # +---+---+---+
  ```
- **If it's an array of strings...**

  ```py
  df = spark.createDataFrame(
      [(1, [ '{"A":300, "B":400}', '{ "A":500,"B": 600}' ]),
       (2, [ '{"A": 800, "B": 900}' ])],
      ['ID', 'input_array'])
  df.printSchema()
  # root
  #  |-- ID: long (nullable = true)
  #  |-- input_array: array (nullable = true)
  #  |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
  ```

  ...you can first use [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) to move every array's element into rows thus resulting in a column of string type, then use [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json) to create Spark data types from the strings and finally expand `*` the structs into columns.

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F

  df = df.withColumn('input_array', F.explode('input_array'))
  df = df.withColumn('input_array', F.from_json('input_array', 'struct<A:long,B:long>'))
  df = df.select('ID', 'input_array.*')

  df.show()
  # +---+---+---+
  # | ID|  A|  B|
  # +---+---+---+
  # |  1|300|400|
  # |  1|500|600|
  # |  2|800|900|
  # +---+---+---+
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove square brackets by using `regexp_replace` or `substring` functions
Then you can transform strings with multiple jsons to an array by using `split` function
Then you can unwrap the array and make new row for each element in the array by using `explode` function
Then you can handle column with json by using `from_json` function

Doc: [pyspark.sql.functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

If Input_array is string then you need to parse this string as a JSON and then explode it into rows and expand the keys to columns. You can parse the array as using ArrayType data structure:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


data = [('1', '[{"A":300, "B":400},{ "A":500,"B": 600}]')
       ,('2', '[{"A": 800, "B": 900}]')
       ]

my_schema = ArrayType(
                      StructType([
                          StructField('A', IntegerType()),
                          StructField('B', IntegerType())
                      ])
                      )
    
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['id', 'Input_array'])\
    .withColumn('Input_array', F.from_json('Input_array', my_schema))\
    .select("id", F.explode("Input_array").alias("Input_array"))\
    .select("id", F.col('Input_array.*'))

df.show(truncate=False)

# +---+---+---+
# |id |A  |B  |
# +---+---+---+
# |1  |300|400|
# |1  |500|600|
# |2  |800|900|
# +---+---+---+
```